# Je kiu grado estas ĝuste reordigi "OSVV[V[....]]" al "OVSV[V[...]]"?

Tags: verbs, word-order

Kiam verbfrazo havas pli ol unu verbon, kiam (kaj kiom) estas ĝuste aŭ malĝuste meti la subjekton post la "kapverbon" kaj antaŭ la aliajn verbojn? Jen estas ekzemplo [eble iomete absurdeta].

> Kion vi {volas} {peni provi fari}? (la pli kutima)
> Kion {volas} vi {peni provi fari}? (la malpli kutima)

Laŭ mia kompreno (kaj esprimcelo) de la frazo malpli kutima, la "kion" estas la objekto de la fina verbo, «fari», ne de la «volas». Se mi anstataŭe volus ke la «kion» estu la objekto de la «volas», mi aldonus «por» antaŭen de la «peni». Kiom ĝusta estas tiu penso? Mi esperas ke tiuj ekzemploj ne estas tro strangaj.

Ĉiuokaze, mi povas elpensi kelke da frazoj, kiuj ŝajnas al mi iel malĝustaj. Jen unu tia frazo.

> Kion klopodis vi fari?

Evidente, la «kion» ne povas esti la objekto de la «klopodis», ĉar «klopodi» estas netransitiva. Kiel en la frazo(j) antaŭa(j), la «kion» denove nur estas la objekto de la fina verbo «fari».  Malgraŭe, dum parolado [rapida], la [pseŭdo-]OVS-eco eble farigus konfuzon. Do, se la unuaj du estas ĝustaj, ĉu ankaŭ tiu estas ĝusta, **koncerne al nur gramatiko**?

(se vi miras, kial mi tiel uzus "OVSV...", estas pro influo de aliaj lingvoj, kiel la franca)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La ordo estas sufiĉe libera. Viaj tri frazoj ĝustas (maloftaj aranĝoj, en kiuj partoprenas pluraj verboj, povas tamen malhelpi komprenon, eĉ se ili estas gramatike ĝustaj).

> Kion klopodis vi fari?

Tie `klopodi` funkcias iel kiel `voli` aŭ `povi`. `klopodi fari` estas grupo verba (la subjekto povas esti antaŭe, meze) kaj `kion` nur povus rilati `fari`.

Ekzemplo de tia uzo, kie la objekto estas for de la ĉefa verbo kaj la subjekto inter la du verboj de la grupo:

> Ne trudu, kion devus mi rifuzi. (Ifigenio en Taŭrido, Zamenhof 1908)

Notu ke `kion` estas objekto de `rifuzi` (aŭ de `devi rifuzi`), ne de `devi`. Tiu ordo ne estas ofta (ofta estus *kion mi devus rifuzi*), sed malofteco ne igas ĝin malĝusta.

> Kion vi {volas} {peni provi fari}? (la pli kutima)
>
> Kion {volas} vi {peni provi fari}? (la malpli kutima)

Oni denove havas tiun *grupon verban*, ĉi okaze `voli + peni provi fari`, do la subjekto, povus aperi antaŭe, meze (kie aperas la `+` signo, kiel en la citaĵo Zamenhofa supre).

Pri ordo, notu ke la parto post la `+` signo estas menciita ĉi tiel en PMEG: [*Principe I-verbo, kiu dependas de povi, devi aŭ voli, estas rekta objekto de tiu verbo.*](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/i-verboj/aliaj_frazroloj/kun_povi_devi_voli.html) Tio signifas ke la ordo por rekta objekto povas *principe*  ankaŭ esti aplikata al ĝi.